# Regex Find/Replace char on a line before a specific word

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hope here is the right place to write ask this question.
I am preparing a script to import to a database using notepad++.

I have a huge file that has rows like that:

> (10496, '69055-230', 'Rua', '5', 'Manaus', 'Parque 10 de Novembro',
>   'AM')**,**
>   INSERT INTO dne id, cep, tp_logradouro, logradouro, cidade,
>   bairro, uf VALUES

Is there a way using FIND/REPLACE to replace the ',' to ';' on every line before the INSERT statement?

I am not sure how to match the end of the line before a specific word.

The result would be

> (10496, '69055-230', 'Rua', '5', 'Manaus', 'Parque 10 de Novembro',
>   'AM')**;**
>   INSERT INTO dne id, cep, tp_logradouro, logradouro, cidade,
>   bairro, uf VALUES

Comment: I think you can easily replace `,\nINSERT INTO` with `;\nINSERT INTO`, just make sure to select _Extended_ in _Search Mode_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Find what:</kbd> `,(?=\s*INSERT)`

<kbd>Replace with:</kbd> `;`

---

#### Description

- `,` matches a literal comma
- `(?=\s*INSERT)` is a lookeahead that will assert for (but won't consume)

  - `\s*` any number of white spaces (including newlines)
  - `INSERT` as literal

---

If you also want to replace any commas before the end of the file, use

```
,(?=\h*\R\h*INSERT|\s*\z)
```

Note both expressions would fail if you have another instance of a comma followed by `INSERT` that shouldn't be replaced, but in that case you should specify it in the question.

Comment: I believe this will fail to replace the `VALUES` clause of the very last `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Tim Indeed, I was sticking to what the OP specified as "*on every line before the INSERT*". It can be easily fixed with `\z` of course

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a regular expression for that.

1. Select **Extended** in **Search Mode**
2. Replace `,\nINSERT INTO` with `;\nINSERT INTO`

This matches `,` at the end of a line just before `INSERT INTO` at the beginning of the next line. Keep in mind that `\n` will match only in a Linux/Unix/Mac OS X file. For Windows use `\r\n`, for Mac OS Classic `\r` ([reference](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_line_ending_char.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the `INSERT` statements will all have the form:

```
INSERT INTO table col1, col2, col3, ...
VALUES (val1, val2, val3, ...),
                             ^^ what you want to replace
```

Assuming that the only place that `),` will be observed is the end of the `VALUES` line, then you can just can just do the following replacement:

**Find:** `),$`
**Replace:** `);$`

You can do this replacement with the regex option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Using sublim text or notepad++, click CTRL+h and replace all ")INSERT," by ");INSERT"